# Visual Studio Team Services vNext build webpack error

Tags: npm, webpack, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I use webpack to packaging my Angular2 app. If I use my npm run build:prod in the vNext hosted build i recive this error:

```
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4167668Z npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\a\1\s\package.json'
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4177672Z npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\a\1\s\package.json'
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4177672Z npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4177672Z npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4177672Z npm ERR! enoent 
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4297670Z 
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4297670Z npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4297670Z npm ERR!     C:\a\1\s\npm-debug.log
2016-11-10T19:58:29.4457679Z ##[error]Npm failed with error: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd failed with return code: 4294963238
```

I have this steps:

1. Nuget restore
2. npm install
3. build solution
4. Test assemblies
5. npm run build:prod

Locally the npm run build:prod works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand Advanced section in Run WebPack Build Production build step, then specify the working folder that contains your package.json.

Comment: ha. looks like that from yesterday to today the mask is changed. the advanced point is missing but there is a working folder textbox. Setting the working folder makes the build work. Thx